# Why is the greeting function not defined and how to change the code

Tags: python

```py
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
  def greeting(self):
    """Outputs a message with the name of the person"""
    print("Hello! My name is {name}.".format(name=self.name)) 

help(greeting)
```

The error message says

```
Error on line 8:
  help(greeting)
NameError: name 'greeting' is not defined
```

Comment: `greeting` is not available in the global scope. It is inside a class. Try `Person.greeting`

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference the class you placed the method under:

```
help(Person.greeting)
```

```
Help on function greeting in module __main__:

greeting(self)
    Outputs a message with the name of the person
```

Or you could output help on the class itself:

```
help(Person)
```

```
Help on class Person in module __main__:

class Person(builtins.object)
 |  Person(name)
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, name)
 |      Initialize self.  See help(type(self)) for accurate signature.
 |  
 |  greeting(self)
 |      Outputs a message with the name of the person
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```